# Bidirectional attribute binding and nested directives behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have nested directives that are supposed to work sort of like the `<select>` element. When one of the items inside my "select" element is clicked, it's supposed to fire an event which should be intercepted by the parent directive and acted upon. However, I'm experiencing some weird behavior where the bidirectional data binding doesn't update correctly.

In the linked **[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqnGGy9wkpoRyljU148Q?p=preview)**, when you click `Assign "bar" as a value`, it doesn't work the first click. It only works the second click.

Why is that?

Here's the code in question:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = {
    value: 'foo'
  }

  $scope.processForm = function() {
    console.log('processForm function on controller executed.')
    $scope.newValue = $scope.name.value
  }
});


app.directive('aaButtonGroup',
  function($rootScope) {
    return {
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        aaChange: '&'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $rootScope.$on('xyzClick', function() {
          console.log('aaChange expression on aaButtonGroup executed.')
          scope.aaChange()
        })
      }
    }
  }
)

app.directive('aaButtonGroupItem',
  function($rootScope) {
    return {
      template: '<a href="#" ng-click="processClick(\'bar\')">Assign "bar" as a value</a>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
      },
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.processClick = function(key) {
          console.log('aaButtonGroupItem processClick function executed.')
          scope.ngModel = key

          $rootScope.$broadcast('xyzClick')
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

And the HTML

```
<aa-button-group aa-change="processForm()">
  <aa-button-group-item
    ng-model="name.value"></aa-button-group-item>
</aa-button-group>
<pre>Value: {{newValue || 'Undefined'}}</pre>
```

Here's the **[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqnGGy9wkpoRyljU148Q?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here's two ways to fix this:

**$setViewValue fix**

Replace: `scope.ngModel = key;`

With: `ngModelController.$setViewValue(key);`

(and add `require: '^ngModel',` and `ngModelController` as the 4th parameter to your link) like this:

```
  require: '^ngModel',
  replace: true,
  link: function(scope,element,attrs,ngModelController) {
    scope.processClick = function(key) {
      ngModelController.$setViewValue(key);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('xyzClick')
    }
```

[$setViewValue plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V8ZGOox49kR8vhLmYS4D?p=preview)

**$watch fix**

Rather than bind `newValue` to `name.value` yourself based on the event firing, let Angular handle it via a watch:

$scope.processForm = function() {
     $scope.$watch('name.value',function () {
        $scope.newValue = $scope.name.value;
     })
  }

[watch plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TdhhaHAyKqWimVEd44Eo)

**Underlying issue**

Timing.  When you execute this line `scope.ngModel = key;` the change doesn't immediately propagate to the actual `ngModel`.  The model will be updated on the next `$digest` cycle.

You can confirm this by adding these logs:

```
scope.ngModel = key;
console.log("key ",key);
console.log("view value ",ngModelController.$viewValue);
console.log("model value ",ngModelController.$modelValue);
```

Which, when you click the button, will display:

> key  bar
>   view value  foo
>   model value  foo

Using `$setViewValue` updates`ngModel` immediately so you don't have the `$digest` delay.  So:

```
ngModelController.$setViewValue(key);
```

results in:

> key  bar
>   view value  bar
>   model value  bar

Yet another solution is to place a `$timeout` where you set `newValue` so that it happens after the digest cycle is complete:

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
   $timeout( function() {
     $scope.newValue = $scope.name.value;
   },0);
 }
```

But I think either using a `$watch` or setting the model directly are cleaner solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me understand this, but isn't `scope { ngModel: '=' }` supposed to establish automatic two-way binding? Why am I required to do some manual work here?

Comment: The two way binding on `name.value` is established.  But then you're also manually binding `newValue` based on an event firing.  It's the manual binding you're doing which is complicating things a bit since it's firing before Angular's binding.  Another approach would be to use a watch handle the binding of `newValue`.  Ultimately this is rooted in Javascripts lack of a mechanism to request notification of changes to a variable.  ECMA 6 will add an object.observe that may help a lot.  Meanwhile, unfortunately, the two way data binding does have a timing aspect to it.

Comment: I added the $watch option to the answer- depending on the rest of your architecture, that may be a cleaner solution.